# Check for null/blank while inserting into MarkLogic DB using MLCP

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8, mlcp, marklogic-7

I am exploring MarkLogic database and have been trying to import data into it by using MarkLogic content pump. Here is the gist of the csv file.

```
firstname, middlename, lastname, address1, address2, city, state, zip, country
Rajath,,A,No 20 GN,16th cross,Bangalore,KA,560029,IN
Rajath1,,,No 75,,Dharwad,KA,560057,IN
Rajath2,,B,No 66,,Haveri,KA,560034,IN
Rajath3,,D,No 24A ,25th cross,Raichur,KA,560095,IN
Rajath4,,,No 36B,,Coorg,KA,,IN
```

I was successfully able to insert it in the DB. Here is the inserted document.

```
{
    "firstname" : "Rajath4",
    "middlename" : "",
    "lastname" : "",
    "address1" : "No 36B",
    "address2" : "",
    "city" : "Coorg",
    "state" : "KA",
    "zip" : "",
    "country" : "IN"
}
```

It is even inserting the values which are blank/null. Is there a way to specify to ignore the fields which are blank/null while inserting into ML?
Here is what I am expecting.

```
{
    "firstname" : "Rajath4",
    "address1" : "No 36B",
    "city" : "Coorg",
    "state" : "KA",
    "country" : "IN"
}
```

And also how to maintain an auto-generated primary_key/sequence for each documents that we insert? If the id already exists, it should merge/update the document.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a custom transform for filtering the data with your own code.

Also MLCP has the ability to do a unique ID - but per run, not globally. But luckilly, the custom transform feature allows you to also change the URI if you like(so you provide the logic to make it unique) - addressing both of your challenges.

[DOC: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mlcp.pdf](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mlcp.pdf)

**Relevant Sections**:
   - **4.17** - Custom Transforms
   - **4.17.5** - Sample Transform (here add your code to filter the content. in your case, you may prefer to invoke a function in javascript. But that is all a personal choice.)
   - **4.17.6**  - Changing the URI

**Fun** note 4.17.6 also includes explaining how to change the document type.  If you are an xslt person, yuou might decide to have MLCP provide XML, then a template to purge the empty elements and then transform and save to a json object at the end.

---

A note of caution: if you use MLCP with the fastload option, then I think changing the URI will negate the benefit of fastload(or something like that)

Comment: thanks for your answer. Will check and will give it a try.

Comment: If you are hitting just a single node and don;t need the power and robustness of some of the MLCP features, then Justin's suggestion is probably simpler. The sample NOde.js connection code provided is a starting point and then you just need to add the bit to loop through the CSV, clean it and pass it in as JSON. But then again, learning MLCP transforms may be valuable for future uses as well, so this is a nice exercise if it is something you will continue to need.

Comment: Got it. Thanks David

Comment: lets say I just want to upload the csv file using mlcp without using the custom transform but create a primarykey or sequence key for each and every document I insert, how to go about that?

Comment: The fastest way I would accomplish that would be to use AWK and add a GUID column to the CSV. Then reference that column as the key for the URI... Using MLCP, you can use the '-generate_uri ' option, but that is only per import, so it is not necessarily unique (which you require). You should be able to make something unique with a combination of a unique uri-prefix per import in combination with the flag mentioned.

Comment: Thanks will try this too.

Answer (score 3):

CSV isn’t specific enough to distinguish between null, empty string, and undefined.

For example, does the following CSV

```
amount,type,category
1,,C
```

map to

```
{ "amount": 1, "type": null, "category": "C" }
```

or

```
{ "amount": 1, "type": "", "category": "C" }
```

or

```
{ "amount": 1, "category": "C" }
```

?

If you’d like more control over how your CSV is parsed, another option is to pre-process the CSV in Java or Node.js and insert the resulting JSON or XML documents using the [Java](https://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/document/DocumentWriteSet.html) or [Node.js](https://docs.marklogic.com/jsdoc/documents.html#write) Client APIs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes even I thought of the same thing. But still wanted to know if there was something which can be done using mlcp.